# XML to text file via XSLT creating leading spaces and blank lines

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

Using XSLT to transform the simplest file to text inserts a leading blank line, a trailing blank line, and leading spaces.  How is this avoided in the case that I need more control over the text output?

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
```

```xml
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" Version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="text"/>
<xsl:template match="book">
     <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result is:

```
(blank line)
    XML Developer's Guide
    Midnight Rain
(blank line)
```

I'd expect:

```
XML Developer's Guide
Midnight Rain
```

Comment: How can that *XSLT* work without traversing the tree from root, *catalog*? Are you running the *Identity Transform* template?

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="book"><xsl:value-of select="title"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Without indentation and extraneous line break is easiest here.

Otherwise the following would do:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
```

Also to have several spaces normalized to one single space:

```
<xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(description)"/>
```

The last technique is to emit explicit spaces and newlines.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  The first suggestion produces the exact same output as before (blank lines and spaces).  The second suggestion removes all blank lines and spaces between values but creates a file with contents of "XML Developer's GuideMidnight Rain"  I didn't try the last suggestion as I'm not sure it applies here.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the removal of leading/trailing spaces, you may also need to add the following line:

```
<xsl:output method="text" indent="no" />
```

Comment: `indent` has no meaning when the output method is`text`.